# CakePHP 3.5 Always apply asText() MySQL function to Spatial field

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, spatial

I have a custom `PolygonType` which represents a `POLYGON()` field in a MySQL table.

```
class PolygonType extends BaseType implements ExpressionTypeInterface
{
    public function toPHP($value, Driver $d)
    {
        // $value is binary, requires unpack()
    }
}
```

I can use `$query->func()->astext()` on *every* find, but I would like to know if it's possible to *always* apply MySQL's `AsText()` function when selecting this field instead (similar to how `toExpression()` can be used when inserting data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [ndp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685273/cakephp-3-5-always-apply-astext-mysql-function-to-spatial-field/48688661#48688661), it's possible to inspect the field types via `$query->getDefaultTypes()` and apply a SQL function as required. However, `$value` is empty if no fields are initially stated (e.g. when using `Table::get()` so there's also a check for this.

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary)
{
    $query->traverse(
        function (&$value) use ($query) {

            if (is_array($value) && empty($value)) {
                $query->all();
            }

            $defaultTypes = $query->getDefaultTypes();

            foreach ($value as $key => $field) {
                if (in_array($defaultTypes[$field], ['point', 'polygon'])) {
                    $value[$key] = $query->func()->astext([
                        $this->aliasField($field) => 'identifier'
                    ]);
                }
            }

            $query->select($value);
        },
        ['select']
    );
}
```

Comment: `$query->func()->astext()` appears to be undefined, it is also not mentioned in the documentation. Where did you define it?

Comment: Found it: `$query->func()->...` works also for not already defined functions. However, as of MySQL 5.7.6 `AsText()` is deprecated and `ST_AsText()` should be used. So we should use `$query->func()->ST_AsText()`

Comment: My monologue is getting out of hand, but when only default fields are requested, the query will be executed twice because of `$query->all()`. By using `$query->select($this)` (passing the table object) it will select all fields, without having to execute it first.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no such functionality, type classes and select clause contents never touch.

If you wanted to apply this to all finds, then you could for example use the `Model.beforeFind()` event, traverse the `select` clause and transform the fields to expressions. Here's a quick and dirty example, where `field` is the name of the `POLYGON` type column:

```
// in the respective table class

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

// ...

public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, \ArrayObject $options, $primary)
{
    $query->traverse(
        function (&$value) use ($query) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                $value = $query->aliasFields($this->getSchema()->columns());
            }

            foreach ($value as $key => $field) {
                if (is_string($field) &&
                    $this->aliasField($field) === $this->aliasField('field')
                ) {
                    unset($value[$key]);
                    $value[key($query->aliasField($field))] = $query->func()->AsText([
                        $this->aliasField('field') => 'identifier'
                    ]);
                }
            }
        },
        ['select']
    );
}
```

You may have to account for `$field` as expressions too, in case the field might be used in one and needs to be converted there too.

Another way would be to convert the data on PHP level in the type class' `toPHP()` method, as already indicated in your code example.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Lifecycle Callbacks > beforeFind](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforefind)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::traverse()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_traverse)**

Comment: Thank you! I noticed when using `Table::get()` the traverse callback is passed an empty array, do you think this is the correct behaviour? I'll post my working solution below.

Comment: @robmcvey Ah, sorry, forgot about that, that would also happen for finds where no fields are being selected explicitly, the default fields would be added automatically at a later point, right before the SQL is being generated. You can retrieve the columns from the schema and add them, see my updated answer.