# CakePHP 3 - Use SQL function in select() by default in table object

Tags: cakephp, orm, model, cakephp-3.0

I am setting up a system for a database with some `POINT` columns. I used the cookbook example to build a custom type and it seems to be working. However, to process the `POINT`s I need to `SELECT` them in a special way:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(location) as location ...
```

This isn't hard with the query builder:

```
$this->Houses->find()->select(['location' => 'ST_AsText(location)'])
```

However, I would prefer to have this happen by default.

I was thinking of using the `beforeFind` event, but I cannot find the right functions for the following pseudo-code:

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary)
{
    if 'location' in query->getSelectedFields():
         replace 'location' by 'location' => 'ST_AsText(location)'
}
```

**How can I have a field be replaced by a function when it is going to be included?** Ideally even when I haven't called `->select(...)` yet from a controller.

*Older comparable question on CakePHP discourse:* https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/read-data-from-spatial-mysql-field-point-polygon/2124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution in [CakePHP 3.5 Always apply asText() MySQL function to Spatial field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685273/cakephp-3-5-always-apply-astext-mysql-function-to-spatial-field).

This works well for CakePHP 3.8. I decided to put the event handling inside a behavior to make it easy to reuse:

```
<?php
// src/Model/Behavior/SpatialBehavior.php    

namespace App\Model\Behavior;

use Cake\ORM\Behavior;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use ArrayObject;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

/**
 * Spatial behavior
 * 
 * Make sure spatial columns are loaded as text when needed.
 * 
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Table $_table
 */
class SpatialBehavior extends Behavior
{

    /**
     * Default configuration.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_defaultConfig = [];

    /**
     * Callback before each find is executed
     * 
     * @param Event $event
     * @param Query $query
     * @param ArrayObject $options
     * @param type $primary
     */
    public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary)
    {
        $query->traverse(function (&$value) use ($query)
        {
            if (is_array($value) && empty($value))
            {
                // Built up standard query when ->select() was never used
                //$query->all(); // Execute query to learn columns
                $query->select($this->_table);
            }

            $defaultTypes = $query->getDefaultTypes();

            foreach ($value as $key => $field)
            {
                if (in_array($defaultTypes[$field], ['point', 'polygon']))
                {
                    $value[$key] = $query->func()->ST_AsText([
                        $this->_table->aliasField($field) => 'identifier'
                    ]);
                }
            }

            $query->select($value);
        }, ['select']);
    }

}
```

In my table object:

```
class HousesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        //...
        $this->addBehavior('Spatial');
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using cake 4 with some legacy code since cake 2, the `$query->getDefaultTypes();` for the column I am using is a String type, so that solution didn't work...

The solution I found was this:

```php
    public function beforeFind(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event, \Cake\ORM\Query $query, \ArrayObject $options, $primary): void
    {
        // ->sql() transforms the query, setting the select fields when it is not setted
        $query->sql();

        $select = $query->clause('select');
        $fields = array_keys($select);

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            if (in_array($field, [geometry fields])) {
                $select[$field] = 'ST_AsText(DeliveryFees.polygon)';
            }
        }
        $query->select($select, overwrite: true);
    }
```